# Cannot install Hamachi on macOS Sierra 10.12

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, macos, kernel-panic

My Mac book won't let me install `hamachi` or use some programs. The problem I tried to install says `hams.kext` or `hamns.kext` was installed incorrectly and told me to reinstall it, I tried looking into the web but no one has the same problem. How do I reinstall `hams.kext`, `Hamns.kext`? I waited 5 days for a response on my other article I made, but no response.

- macOS Sierra 10.12
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)
- Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB

Comment: Oh and this is the error log it gives me when i try to install hamachi. http://imgur.com/a/CAnCV

Comment: Please provide the log as text it is unreadable

Comment: Please visit the help center how to ask questions. Follow some other guidelines like: post text as text (and not as screenshots). Make your question readable by formatting the text properly and using proper punctuation and spacing. Don't add question details in comments. You can always edit your question. Don't use "Help me please" as header!

Comment: Wood do u mean?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to root Library => Extensions and remove the old Hamns.kext then re install Hamachi. Seems to work for about a month then needs a re install.